# How to remove child SKSpriteNode from parent SKSpriteNode without killing child

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, parent-child, skspritenode, skaction

I have a dragon holding an egg. The eggNode is a child of the dragonNode.

The dragon is flying across screen horizontally.

When the dragon reaches the rightmost part of screen, the dragon resets to the leftmost part of screen.

I have implemented the dragon dropping the egg to the position of a turret on ground. The dragon drops the egg in touchesEnded, using this function.

```
func shootProjectile(){

    //aim
    let dx = turretNode.position.x - dragonNode.position.x
    let dy = turretNode.position.y - dragonNode.position.y
    let angle = atan2(dy, dx)

    dragonProjectileNode.zRotation = angle

    //Seek
    let vx = turrentNode.position.x
    let vy = turrentNode.position.y

    let shootAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(vx, vy),duration: 2.25)
    dragonProjectileNode.runAction(shootAction)
}
```

However, since the egg is still a child of the dragon, the egg will reset to the left side of the screen with the dragon, even after it has been dropped.

How do i fix this? Is there a way to remove the child from parent without killing the egg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not remove a child from a parent without removing the child from the scene completely. I fixed my problem by simply:

1. removing the parent/child relationship from my code.
2. put createEggNode function in my shootProjectile function. (still call function on touchesEnded)
3. put eggNode position at the position of dragon.